Define default value in abstract class
I have this abstract class
abstract class Shape {
  Path _path = Path();
  Color _color = Colors.black;
  double _strokeWidth = 2;
  PaintingStyle _paintingStyle = PaintingStyle.stroke;

  DrawObject({Color? color, double? strokeWidth}) {
    _color = color ?? Colors.black;
    _strokeWidth = strokeWidth ?? 2;
  }
}

and this extend
class Circle extends Shape {
  Circle({
    Color? color,
    required super.offset,
    required super.size,
    required double strokeWidth,
  }) : super() {
    _color = color ?? Colors.black; // this line
    _path = setPath();
    _strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
  }
}

Now I have to check null for every shape I created.
Can I use abstract class constructor for define the default value only once?
It's dart btw

I presume Shape is meant to be DrawObject (or vice-versa)?  The derived Circle class already invokes the base class constructor; that's what super() does.  Instead use super(color: color, strokeWidth: strokeWidth) and let the base class constructor apply its default value.  Or better, use super parameters and make the derived class's constructor use super.color and super.strokeWidth.

Just use super.color in Circle. Below is reduced compilable example (you can try it in dartpad:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

abstract class Shape {
  Path _path = Path();
  Color _color = Colors.black;
  Color get color => _color;
  
  double _strokeWidth = 2;
  PaintingStyle _paintingStyle = PaintingStyle.stroke;

  Shape({Color? color, double? strokeWidth}) {
    _color = color ?? Colors.black;
    _strokeWidth = strokeWidth ?? 2;
  }
}

class Circle extends Shape {
  Circle({
    super.color, // <-- solution
    required double strokeWidth,
  }) : super() {
    _strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
  }
}


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final c = Circle(strokeWidth: 2.0);
    
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello, World! c.color is: ${c.color}'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

